# Weird response from ping

Tags: ping

I have a server called "Otto"
This has an internal IP address of 10.0.10.210

We have had a power failure today, and, although the server room is protected by UPS, things haven't worked properly since.
For example. I can RDP to otto by its ip address 10.0.10.210
But not using it's name

When I ping otto, i get this odd respone:
http://twitpic.com/12ejr0/full

Comment: What is the OS of the server? That looks like an IPv6 address.

Comment: It's Windows 2008 - I have DHCP set up for IPv4... We aren't using ipv6 at all.. or at least not intentionally

Comment: Definitely IPV6 - ping -4 otto will force it into IPv4 mode.

Comment: ok, that's returned the response i was expecting... how can i set the "default" to IPv4?? Up until about an hour ago, pinging otto would of returned 10.0.10.210

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may disable TCP/IPv6 of local area connection . I had same problem for a while ago. It did solve our RDP problem.